# I want if year(picklist) is selected then total investment(number) is display

Tags: formula-field

I have one requirement that if i select `Year__c` ( picklist) field then `Total_INVESTMENT__C` (NUMBER) is display.

Comment: Hi Amit Can you elaborate the following question

Comment: I have  two fields 1-year 2-Total_INVESTMENT(Basically it is formula field) .If i select 2017 from year then Total_INVESTMENT will display .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question try this one in a formula field..VALUE(Text(Year__c ))